# ReactJS State OR Logical Operator always causing type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logical-operators

I've got a simple state setup for a component that still throws the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of undefined` with this code:

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    events: this.props.events,
    activeDate: {
      year: this.props.events[0].year || "",
      month: this.props.events[0].months[0].month || "",
    }
  };

  //...

}
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this errors out instead of just setting the value to null. `undefined` should render the binary operation as false and default to `""`. Can anyone explain?

Comment: What i guess you would want to write, with ESnext, is `year: this?.props?.events?.[0]?.year || "",` (see [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)), but it isn't widely available yet (can always use babel). The issue is, that `this.props.events[0]` is `undefined`, and therefore doesn't have a property called `year`.

Comment: At some moment, even a brief moment, events is undefined or empty. You need to add default values or enhance the logic to handle an empty array or undefined. This can be to add default values at the parent level. That being said deriving state from props is an anti pattern. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks for this! This article really helps clear a few things up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `year: this.props.events[0].year || ""`, I found that that this worked just as well, `year: "" && this.props.events[0].year`. The AND operator will equate to the last true value.

But, as @AlexanderStaroselsky pointed out, this isn't best practice. See this [article](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate that the object in the array at position 0 is not null then use `&&` before to access the property of the array object. Finally, add `||` to specify a default value when both conditions give `null` or `undefined`.

```js
this.props.events[0] && this.props.events[0].year || ""
```